# Upload image on server in Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit

Пытаюсь аплодить битмап через ретрофит на сервер и получаю пустой ответ.
Вот запрос в постмене
POST url HTTP/1.1
Host: host
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 08814ad9-e705-977f-6225-29e3ed81eaee
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post_image"; filename="undefined"
Content-Type: undefined

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="galleryId"

1156
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

сам интерфейс ретрофита

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/web/v1/gallery/upload-gallery-image-multipart")
Call<Object> uploadImage(final @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> post_image);
```

и запрос

StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(mBitmap);
        Map _requestMap = new HashMap<>();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");

```
    _requestMap.put(String.format("%s\"; filename=\"%s", "\"post_image\"", "12345677"),
            new ContentRequestBody(streamContent));

    _requestMap.put("galleryId", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "1682"));

    RetrofitAdapter.getInterface().uploadImage(_requestMap)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<Object> response) {
                    Log.d("DENYSYUK", "onResponse");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("DENYSYUK", "onFailure = " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Отформатируйте правильно код